# Crystal Report Page Number

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to get the current viewing page number of crystal report how is this possible. I am developing desktop application.

Comment: You need to give more information about what language/environment you're working in etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the

crystalReportViewer1.GetCurrentPageNumber();

to find the page user is currently viewing,